# EmailLog table for multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, data-modeling

I need to implement an email log table, which is to be used by a range of entities - each of these entities represent data that us used to create "emailable" documents.

How would I best model this behaviour in the database using Symfony2 and doctrine? There are too many fields to not reuse the EmailLog table and there is also functionality planned that may include an overall log view.

Assuming we have tables quote and order as such document data tables, the most sensible to me seems to be

```
Company\Bundle\Entity\EmailLog:
  type: entity
  table: email_log
  id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        id: true
        column: emlo_id
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
  fields:
    created_at:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
        default: ''
    to:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 500
        fixed: false
        comment: ''

Company\Bundle\Entity\EmailLog:
  type: entity
  table: email_log_link
  id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        id: true
        column: emlo_id
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
  fields:
    quote_id:
        type: int
        nullable: true

    order_id:
        type: int
        nullable: true
```

Is there a better database model?

Should this maybe be solved with a PSR-3 Logger?

Comment: Can you please describe your needs? I think that [Core Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more suitable place for this question. Anyway, I would log the title of the emails, and the `From:` and other headers if you use them.

Comment: @A.L No, we don't do database design reviews at Code Review, it's too high level.

Comment: After thinking about my needs a bit more, I think it makes sense to delete this question. What I am looking for is a solution architecture to store emails with tags and to retrieve them with an API. Is there any service that can do the main load of this?

Comment: @Mast is [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) the best website for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in your mapping file, it seems that you are using Doctrine ORM.

What you are trying to achieve is probably known as an anti-pattern, "[The Alien](http://www.slideshare.net/bonmassar/patterns-antipatterns-with-nosql)", a type of object stored in a relational database with little or no relations to other entities. You are using the database just as a medium of persistence.

Why don't you switch this part of your domain model to a documental database? You design your entities as simple documents and use [Doctrine ODM](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) to map them to Symfony. In addition, converting the actual mapping to an ODM mapping is quite trivial.

Comment: Really good idea to look at this in a new way. I've realised that I built quite a number of Aliens in my career.